# maven artifact repository directory structure specs

Tags: maven-2, repository

I would like to know the specs for the maven repository structure.

I know I could use archiva or nexus to create a repository. I am not interested in those information.

I have tried searching apache's maven website and google with the phrase
"maven  artifact repository structure specs", and I mostly get the development directory structure expected on the maven client.

I would like someone to explain the structure here or point me to a comprehensive single document (i.e. one that does not explain the directory structure by making me follow a never ending trail of links) that explains for example,

- How to create a simple maven repository using a static file system directory, deployed to apache http server.
- or how to create a directory structure on googlecode that would appear as a maven repository.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the specification (long overdue for documenting in Maven itself):

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+Layout+-+Final

That said, I wouldn't refer to that for creating the repository in the way you've described. The best thing to do is to use `mvn deploy:deploy-file` with appropriate parameters to upload the files that you want to, as it can write appropriate metadata and structure for you. This can be done to a filesystem location and synced to the location you want to.

Another alternative is to run a repository manager, like Archiva, and upload using the web interface until you are happy, then sync the directory structure to the location that you want to.