# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jasper-reports, tomcat7, lifecycleexception

I am facing below error while trying to deploy the application on tomcat server. I am deploying the same code from this link: http://krams915.blogspot.in/2010/12/spring-3-mvc-jasper-integration.html without customization yet. **I find the same error is reported on stackoverflow, but none of the solution worked for me**. Hence decided to report once again considering issue for this source code.Please guide.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-jasper-integration]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-jasper-integration]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: SHA1 digest error for org/bouncycastle/crypto/encodings/OAEPEncoding.class
    at sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier.verify(ManifestEntryVerifier.java:220)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:241)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierStream.read(JarVerifier.java:483)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readID(ClassParser.java:201)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2123)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1946)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1931)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1330)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5472)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 6 more

Feb 20, 2016 6:25:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 6 more

Feb 20, 2016 6:25:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 11 more
```

The pom.xml for reference.

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.6</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Project Build -->
    <build>
        <finalName>spring-jasper-integration</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Maybe you should write the small application for testing

Comment: Did you try to use another versions of *JasperReports* library (6.x or 5.x)?

Comment: Loks like Tomcat can not verify one of jasper dependency jar manifest (Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: SHA1 digest error for org/bouncycastle/crypto/encodings/OAEPEncoding.class, bcprov-jdk:138).

Comment: Hi Alex - I already tried with asperReports library 5.x and 6.x, still facing same issue. Not sure whats going wrong. Did you try this source code on your workspace ?

Comment: Hi rell - Even though I'm using latest dependencies causing the same problem, please guide.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. You should make a MCVE. What I did: copy-paste your POM, made a simple empty web-app deployed on Tomcat 7. It worked.

Comment: What solutions did you try? from stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by updating and adding the maven dependencies. When I run the Project, I can see below page and also can download PDF report. I trying to analysed maven conflict which is causing problems with your current maven dependencies.

But you can simply use below below pom.xml and your application will be running fine. The output I can

*Note: I am running my tomcat on port 8085, because oracle is installed on 8080 on my machine*.

[image]

pom.xml

```
<properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Web -->
        <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate Entity Manager -->
        <hibernate-entitymanager-version>3.6.0.Final</hibernate-entitymanager-version>

        <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
        <hibernate-validator-version>5.1.3.Final</hibernate-validator-version>

        <!-- Hibernate JPA API -->
        <hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-version>1.0.1.Final</hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-version>

        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <spring-data-jpa-version>1.9.4.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa-version>

        <!-- Commons DBCP, POOL -->
        <commons-dbcp-version>20030825.184428</commons-dbcp-version>
        <commons-pool-version>20030825.183949</commons-pool-version>
        <c3p0.version>0.9.1.2</c3p0.version>

        <!-- MYSQL Connector-->     
        <mysql.version>5.1.35</mysql.version>

        <!-- Jackson -->
        <jackson.version>1.9.3</jackson.version>

        <standard.version>1.1.2</standard.version>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <aspectj.version>1.8.8</aspectj.version>

        <!-- Jasper Report -->
        <jasperreports.version>6.0.0</jasperreports.version>

        <!-- POI -->
        <poi.version>3.14</poi.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <jcl.slf4j.version>1.7.12</jcl.slf4j.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Web MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring Context Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jasper Reports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>${jasperreports.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-dbcp-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons Pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-pool-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibermnate Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Entity Manager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.1.0.Final</version> -->
            <version>${hibernate-entitymanager-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate JPA 2.0 API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson is a high-performance JSON processor (parser, generator) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache POI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database pooling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- View Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>${standard.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Other Web dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey Guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Groovy All -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <!-- JBoss Repository used for Java EE 6 pieces -->
        <repository>
            <id>repository.jboss.org</id>
            <name>JBoss Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <!-- Project Build -->
    <build>
        <finalName>spring-mvc-jasper</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can forcely update your maven

> mvn clean install -U

2. If this procedure fails, then try to it with hard way

> ```
> find ~/.m2/ -name "*.lastUpdated" | xargs rm
> ```

3. If this procedure also fails, Then try to purge the local repo using the following:

> ```
> mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
> ```

Then make clean and install by this command:

> mvn dependency:purge-local-repository clean install

For better, you can follow the links

1. [How do I remove a cached local artifact that maven fetched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554632/how-do-i-remove-a-cached-local-artifact-that-maven-fetched)
2. [Force maven update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update)

Comment: @javatechnology Would you please share your sample code? so that we can give you better answer

Comment: I place code on https://github.com/JavaNeed/spring-jasper-tutorial.git. If you're able fixed this issue. Let me know. Or you can place your code too

Comment: @javatechnology Your some jar files are not download when i want to install in my PC. please cross-check which jars are needed.

Comment: All the listed dependencies in pom.xml should be downloaded to your local    M2_HOME,

Comment: Did you get a chance to further look at this issue?

Comment: Thanks your suggestion is solve my problem. Also i meet mvn dependency:purge-local-repository command :)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before where you ended up with a corrupted dependency artifact downloaded by Maven. To correct the issue, you can try to clear your maven local cache by following these steps:

[How do I remove a cached local artifact that maven fetched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554632/how-do-i-remove-a-cached-local-artifact-that-maven-fetched)

Comment: Did you tried to run the same code on STS with Java 8? Although I tried this, but still failing.. Please guide now.