# Eclipse doesn't see changes made in a GitHub dependency of a Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, github

I have set up an Eclipse Maven project to use a GitHub repository as a dependency. Now I forked that repository, switched the dependency to the fork, and made a small change to the fork. Now the project still compiles and runs just fine, but Eclipse doesn't see the change, which shows up on GitHub just fine. This got me thinking:

If Eclipse couldn't see the dependency on GitHub, it should have been unable to build the project. On the other hand, if it can get it somehere but doesn't see the change, it must mean that the new fork is not yet properly linked to the project somehow; most likely the old repo still lives somewhere on my local machine and Maven uses it to build the project for reasons I cannot discern. I tried rebuilding and re-importing the project, but it didn't help. I'm new to Maven, so I'm really quite lost in all this. I need to know:

What is causing this? What piece of how Maven/Eclipse/GitHub work am I missing? What file or list do I need to download, update, refresh, or rebuild?

EDIT; pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>l4j-clui</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>launch4j</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dontWrapJar>true</dontWrapJar>
                            <headerType>console</headerType>
                            <jar>eet-demo-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</jar>
                            <outfile>target\EETSender.exe</outfile>
                            <errTitle></errTitle>
                            <cmdLine></cmdLine>
                            <chdir>.</chdir>
                            <priority>normal</priority>
                            <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                            <supportUrl></supportUrl>
                            <stayAlive>true</stayAlive>
                            <restartOnCrash>true</restartOnCrash>
                            <manifest></manifest>
                            <icon></icon>
                            <singleInstance>
                                <mutexName>EETMutex</mutexName>
                                <windowTitle></windowTitle>
                            </singleInstance>
                            <classpath>
                                <mainClass>cz.tomasdvorak.eetdemo.Main</mainClass>
                            </classpath>
                            <jre>
                                <path></path>
                                <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
                                <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
                                <minVersion>1.6.0_1</minVersion>
                                <maxVersion></maxVersion>
                                <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                                <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
                            </jre>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>cz.tomasdvorak.eetdemo.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
         </descriptors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

</plugins>
    </build>

     <groupId>cz.tomasdvorak</groupId>
    <artifactId>eet-demo-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.MiroslavMarecek</groupId>
            <artifactId>eet-client-1</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.MiroslavMarecek</groupId>
                <artifactId>eet-client-1</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Have exactly did you set up the dependency? Can you show the `pom.xml` ?

Comment: Have you actually rebuilt your "dependency"? Like, `mvn clean install`? If not, Maven is still using the version which is cached in your local Maven repository.

Comment: Tried `mvn clean install`, still doesn't see the change.

Comment: @Sargon1 Also try giving your patched fork a different version compared to the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has the jar version changed? If not, the jar is probably cached in your local maven repo. `C:\Users\user-name\.m2`

Check this thread for details: [How do I remove a cached local artifact that maven fetched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554632/how-do-i-remove-a-cached-local-artifact-that-maven-fetched)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Released a new version of the forked repo
2. Changed the version number in the pom to that new version